# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning при попытке обратиться к папке начинающейся с точки ( .folder )

Tags: javascript, node.js

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning при попытке обратиться к папке начинающейся с точки ( .folder )

Использую библиотеку MCLC https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-launcher-core

В root нужно указать путь к папке, а она начинается с точки и возникает ошибка. Как можно обратиться к папке, имя которой начинается с точки?

Comment: покажи как ты путь указываешь

Comment: `root: process.env.APPDATA + "/.minecraft/"`

Comment: Если перед точкой поставить \  это не помогает

Comment: открывая документацию видим что тебе не нужна AppData , ты просто пишешь `root: "./minecraft"`

Comment: Нужна. В документации `./` - это обозначение текущей папки. А мне нужна AppData\Roaming и в ней ".minecraft"

Comment: Стоит по-handle-ить этот rejection и посмотреть на ошибку.